# IBM MQ Docker container not running on Mac 200

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, ibm-mq

I tried to build ibm mq container using below docker compose file.

```
> version: '2.1'
> 
> services:
> ibmmq:
> image: 'docker.io/ibmcom/mq'
> platform: linux/amd64
> environment:
> LICENSE=accept
> MQ_QMGR_NAME=QM1
> ports:
>       - '1414:1414'
>       - '9443:9443'
> volumes:
> ibmmq:/data/ibmmq
> container_name: ibmmq
> 
> volumes:
> ibmmq:
> driver: local
```

I tried to create a container using the `docker compose up -d` command of that file. The image is created but the container is not running and the error is as below.

```
> 
> Running 1/1
> Container ibmmq  Created                                                                                                                                                          0.3s 
> Attaching to ibmmq
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.909Z CPU architecture: amd64
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.912Z Linux kernel version: 5.15.49-linuxkit-pr
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.913Z Base image: Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.5 (Ootpa)
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.914Z Running as user ID 1001 with primary group 0, and supplementary groups 0
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.916Z Capabilities (bounding set): chown,dac_override,fowner,fsetid,kill,setgid,setuid,setpcap,net_bind_service,net_raw,sys_chroot,mknod,audit_write,setfcap
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.916Z seccomp enforcing mode: filtering
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.916Z Process security attributes: none
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:49.917Z No volume detected. Persistent messages may be lost
> ibmmq  | 2023-08-30T13:24:50.162Z You cannot run more than one instance of this program
> ibmmq exited with code 1
>
```

I have a Mac mini (2023), chip Apple m2

I tried changing **icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq** this image, but it didn't work, the error is as below.

> ```
> [+] Running 0/1
>  ⠇ ibmmq Pulling                                                                                                                                                                     0.9s 
> no matching manifest for linux/arm64/v8 in the manifest list entries
> ```

Comment: Looks like you are pulling MQ Container image from dockerHub. Latest MQ container images are published at icr.io/ibm-messaging/mq. Could you please try?

Comment: Hi @Shashi!!!    Tried it but it still didn't work, I updated the ticket.

Comment: Reference `https://cyublog.com/articles/dev-zh/apple-silicon-docker-mysql/` , in Dockerfile  add `--platform linux/amd64` or `docker-compose.yml` add `platform: linux/x86_64` (it looks like run x86 container on arm platform)

Comment: Hi @life888888!!!  I have tried it, but in this ticket I have put the error after running the command docker compose up -d, the same error is coming.

Comment: After you add the parameter `--platform linux/amd64` to `docker-compose.yml`, which image is used to cause the error message? Or have both images been tested?

Comment: Hi @life888888!!! The same problem occurs in both the images

Comment: For Apple Silicon - you will need to build your own container image - please see this post https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/richard-coppen/2023/06/30/ibm-mq-9330-container-image-now-available-for-appl

Answer (score 0):

As @Sashi states the current MQ Container image doesn't support ARM64. Even running with docker emulation mode (`--platform linux/amd64`) The X86-64 image doesn't run on MacOS ARM64.

You can, however, build your own ARM64 image. Instructions are available from the link shared by Sashi, repeated [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/richard-coppen/2023/06/30/ibm-mq-9330-container-image-now-available-for-appl).

You need to make sure that a `IBM-MQ-Advanced-for-Developers-Non-Install-LinuxARM64` is available for the [release](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/downloading-ibm-mq-933-continuous-delivery).

If you have a failed attempt, then remove the contents of the downloads directory

The steps are:

```
git clone https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container.git

cd mq-container

MQ_VERSION=9.3.3.0 make build-devserver
```

Comment: I followed the given steps,I got the below error.!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: **curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
make: *** [downloads/9.3.3.1-IBM-MQ-Advanced-for-Developers-Non-Install-LinuxARM64.tar.gz] Error 22**

Comment: This way is not working for me. How to get access for IBM-MQ-Advanced-for-Developers-Non-Install-LinuxARM64?

curl --fail --location https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/messaging/mqadv/9.3.3.0-IBM-MQ-Advanced-for-Developers-Non-Install-LinuxARM64.tar.gz --output downloads/9.3.3.0-IBM-MQ-Advanced-for-Developers-Non-Install-LinuxARM64.tar.gz
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
make: *** [downloads/9.3.3.0-IBM-MQ-Advanced-for-Developers-Non-Install-LinuxARM64.tar.gz] Error 22

Comment: 403 is a forbidden. I've just rechecked the link and it is working. 9.3.4.0 is the latest version, but 9.3.3.0 is still available. Are you behind a firewall / proxy?